# How to design scenario in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter,and started learning as we as exploring the tool.

Currently we are using Performance Center for Load testing.

Eventually we will move to JMeter.

Here is the scenario how we designed on the PC. Scenario:

- Total No.of users : 451
- Total No.of scripts: 191
- Ramp Up: Start 50 users 8 users for every 10 sec's Duration : 5 min's
- Ramp Up: Start 50 users 8 users for every 10 sec's Duration : 5 min's
- So on..
- Once it reaches to 451 users run for 25 min's Ramp Down: same way how ramped up

Total Test duration : 2 he's 15 min's

Note:Each script has assigned different no.of users I.e users distributed differnt numbers. For ex Script1 assigned users are 10, Script2:8; Script 3: So on...

The same scenario how can I do in jMeter? I know Blaze meter we can define, but not exactly what I mentioned above. Using Blaze meter we can define No.Of users; Rampup 50;Test duration

Comment: What do you mean by "Total No.of scripts: 191 " here...?
What are these scripts...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using the **"Stepping Thread Group"** of JMeter. It is not a default Thread Group of JMeter but you can install the same using JMeter plugins and can use that plugin for creating customized and stepped load for achieving the scenario described by you.

You can also add multiple Stepped Thread Groups for different load pattern in single test plan.

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/

http://testingfreak.com/jmeter/stepping-thread-group/

Comment: Hi Dhiman,   If you look at the scenario Total No.of users : 451 Total No.of scripts: 191.I have tried this way created 2 individual test plan and each test plan again I have added normal thread group because I have define different users for each script. Let's say 1 st script has to run for 6 users & 2nd script has to run for 4 users. So I have assigned 6 users for 1st test plan and for the 2nd one 4 users.Now I have created main test plan which has only stepping thread group  and assigned 10 using merged these 2 scripts to it.now when I ran  it runs for 20 users which is not supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a very simple way to create Jmeter test scripts depending upon the required scenario. 
What I do is, I record my scripts using a chrome extension - blazemeter. It records all the actions I perform on a website. Then the script generated by it can be exported and used in jmeter. In jmeter you can edit the ramp up and threads and everything as per the need.

> [I have written an article on it here -](http://testacy.co.in/performance-testing-jmeter)